rclone group permissions not working
im using rclone to mount google drive but the permissions are completely broken.
im using debian 12
-> sudo namei -l /mnt/cloud/gdrive/gd1/3D
f: /mnt/cloud/gdrive/gd1/3D
drwxr-xr-x root root   /
drwxr-xr-x root root   mnt
drwxr-xr-x root root   cloud
drwxr-xr-x root root   gdrive
drwxrwx--- root gdrive gd1
drwxrwx--- root gdrive 3D
-> sudo eza --icons -lg --time-style "+%s %Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
drwxrwx--- - root 937400039 1719190094 2024-06-23 17:48  gd1
-> eza --icons -lg --time-style "+%s %Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
[./gd1: Permission denied (os error 13)]
-> id
uid=937400003(irl_name) gid=937400003(irl_name) groups={19 others excluded for space},937400039(gdrive)

autofs map:
gd1 -fstype=rclone,rw,uid=0,gid=937400039,dir-perms=0770,file-perms=0770,allow-non-empty,umask=000,fast-list,vfs-cache-mode=writes,config=/etc/rclone/gd/rclone.conf,cache-dir=/var/cache/rclone :gd:

